# Python Selenium - href specific output

Tags: python, selenium, href

I have been working on a project to pull specific href links from a site. Everything is working but I also want to be able to pull only specific data from href link. I haven't been able to figure that part out.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service


service = Service(executable_path="c:/temp/chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)

#Source site
driver.get("site.com")

#The xpath to the links
s = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/div[4]/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td[4]/a").get_attribute('href')
smonth = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/div[4]/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]")

b = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/div[4]/table[1]/tbody/tr[6]/td[4]/a").get_attribute('href')
bmonth = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/div[4]/table[1]/tbody/tr[6]/td[3]")

bb = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/div[4]/table[1]/tbody/tr[28]/td[3]/a").get_attribute('href')
bbmonth = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/div[4]/table[1]/tbody/tr[28]/td[2]")

#The output of the links
print("S:", smonth.text, s, "\nB:", bmonth.text, b, "\nBB:", bbmonth.text, bb)


driver.close()
```

Here is the output

```
S: July 2022 https://bdn-ak-ssl.site.com/software/s96_8_80.exe
B: July 2022 https://bdn-ak-ssl.site.com/software/b43_6_56.exe
BB: July 2022 https://bdn-ak-ssl.site.com/software/bb202_2_100.exe
```

I'm trying to get the output to look like this

```
S: July 2022 https://bdn-ak-ssl.site.com/software/s96_8_80.exe Version: s96_8_80
B: July 2022 https://bdn-ak-ssl.site.com/software/b43_6_56.exe Version: b43_6_56
BB: July 2022 https://bdn-ak-ssl.site.com/software/bb202_2_100.exe Version: bb202_2_100
```

Comment: post the html of the page as well (or confirm the url if it's publicly accessible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

```
import re

output = "BB: July 2022 https://bdn-ak-ssl.site.com/software/bb202_2_100.exe"
result = re.search(r'software/(.*?).exe', output)
result = result.group(1)

output += f" Version: {result}"
print(output)
```

Output

```
BB: July 2022 https://bdn-ak-ssl.site.com/software/bb202_2_100.exe Version: bb202_2_100
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply remove parts of the string to return the version

```
version = s.replace('https://bdn-ak-ssl.site.com/software/','').replace('.exe','')
print('Version: ', version)
```